# What's stopping my camera movement script from receiving input events?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Thanks for reading. I tried posting this on unity answers, but it's been 24 hours and it's still not out of moderation, so maybe I'll have better luck here.

**Background**

I am very new to unity and know I must be missing some critical piece of knowledge to tie this together. I've created a blank game with some placeholder terrain and added a main camera to the 3d orthographic scene. I would like the user to be able to move the camera along a parallel plane to the ground.

**What I've Done**

I've added a starter camera codebehind I found online along with an event system, rigid body, ray caster, and a bunch of other things I saw online for this sort of thing. All of these components are in the same layer.

**The Problem**

My camera script's update method is hit when I put that in for testing but it doesn't receive any other events even though it implements the appropriate interfaces. I'm guessing I have something blocking the input from hitting the script or I do not have a component I need in order for those events to fire.

I'm testing on desktop for now but I want this to run on mobile (although from what I've read the events I'm subscribing to should be universal). Can anyone spot any oversights or deficiencies in my setup so far? Here are some screenshots.

Thanks!

**My Setup**

[image]

Edit: by request, here is the camera script I'm using. I know it doesn't do what I want yet but the issue I'd like to tackle right now is why it doesn't seem to be wired up correctly. Like I said, if I put an update method in here it is hit but none of my other logs are hit.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

// The touch is in 2D but the scene is in 3D, so touch.x => scene.x, touch.y => scene.z, and nothing change (0) => scene.y since y is up


public class TouchCamera : MonoBehaviour,
  IPointerDownHandler,
  IDragHandler,
  IPointerUpHandler
{
private Vector3 prevPointWorldSpace;
private Vector3 thisPointWorldSpace;
private Vector3 realWorldTravel;

private int drawFinger;
private bool drawFingerAlreadyDown;


public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer down");
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == true)
        return;
    drawFinger = data.pointerId;
    drawFingerAlreadyDown = true;

    prevPointWorldSpace = data.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
    // in this example we'll put it under finger control...
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer drag");
    if (drawFingerAlreadyDown == false)
        return;
    if (drawFinger != data.pointerId)
        return;

    thisPointWorldSpace = data.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;

    realWorldTravel = thisPointWorldSpace - prevPointWorldSpace;
    _processRealWorldtravel();

    prevPointWorldSpace = thisPointWorldSpace;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer up");
    if (drawFinger != data.pointerId)
        return;

    drawFingerAlreadyDown = false;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
}

private void _processRealWorldtravel()
{
    Debug.Log("Updating camera position");
    Vector3 pot = transform.position;

    pot.x += realWorldTravel.x;
    pot.z += realWorldTravel.y;
    transform.position = pot;
}
}
```

**Final Edit for the Solution**
Thank you very much to Juan Bayona Beriso for helping me in chat with this configuration. Here is what we ended up with that now works:

The camera object has a Rigidbody and Physics 2D Raycaster attached to it. The scene now has a new Canvas object with a Graphics Raycaster (blocking mask set to everything and blocking objects set to none) and an event system with the standalone input module enabled. That canvas also has a child UI object that covers the screen and has the camera script attached. As a curiosity, it required a text component in order for the script to start receiving the events -- this only made a difference when the Raycast Target option was selected. Screenshots below.

[image: Main Camera]

[image: Canvas]

[image: Camera Script Container]

[image: Script Exerpt]

Comment: Please copy and paste here the script.

Comment: Added. Like I said, I'm more interested in what's not wired up properly than I am about how the camera script does or doesn't do what I want yet. Mainly I want to get my debug logs hit.

Comment: You just want to pan the camera with the mouse? That's it?

Comment: Yes, just panning with the mouse or touches. Once I know what I'm doing I'll add in pinch zoom and things, but none of that matters until my script receives events.

Comment: Based on the documentation Raycasting of EventSystem goes from the camera into the depth so I think here's the problem.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misusing the `EventSystem`, `OnPointerDown`, `OnDrag` and all those functions, they are called when you have a `PhysicsRaycaster` in your `Camera` object and you press or drag over an UI Element or and object with a collider.

In your code you don't have any of these, you have a camera so you are not actually pointer down over it or dragging on it.

You have two options:

Either put this script in a plane with a collider or GUI element that is inside the camera and moves with it, or use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`, `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` in the `Update` function

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is starting to make some sense. Is there a preferred approach between the box collider in a plane or the the bound gui element? I'm thinking that if I go the collider route I might end up with issues once I start populating the plane with other objects, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I've done what I understood from what you suggested and it seems like I still have something misconfigured.

Here is my new setup:

http://i.imgur.com/UoFRErz.png

http://i.imgur.com/iyyp3K7.png

http://i.imgur.com/ppERhzl.png

http://i.imgur.com/Pr5UWlx.png

Sorry for the screenshots. I can put this in the original post if that is better.

Comment: Thanks. My camera now has a physics 2d raycaster with the event mask set to everything. No change yet.

Comment: Thanks, but still  no luck. Do I need to add an event system somewhere, possibly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135982/discussion-between-juan-bayona-beriso-and-s-c).

Comment: I've updated the question with the final configuration. Thank you very much for your help!